# Is It Possible to Query User from Contact

Tags: soql

To query User Profile Name from Contact, It is Possible

Example Query Like :
select Id,FirstName,LastName,(Select Id,Name,Isactive,Profile.Name from user) from Contact

Thanks
Nagarjuna

Answer (score 3):

**Query for profiles of users**

```
SELECT Id, Firstname, Lastname, ProfileId, Profile.Name FROM User
```

**Query Last modified user from Contact**

```
SELECT ID, Firstname, Lastname, LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name FROM Contact WHERE ID = :YOUR_CONTACT_ID
```

**Query related users of contacts "Community users"**

```
SELECT ID, ContactId, Contact.Firstname, Contact.Lastname, ProfileId, Profile.Name FROM User WHERE ContactID = :YOUR_CONTACT_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  for( Contact c : [select Id,FirstName,LastName,LastModifiedBy.Name, LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name from Contact limit 1]){
System.debug('cont ' + c.FirstName + ' prof '+ c.LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name);
```

}

Comment: Thanks AtulRajguru,i tried above query  i am getting Id,FirstName,LastName,LastModifiedBy.Name but i am not getting LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name and i also no need LastModifiedBy.Profile.Name because  daily schedule bacth will  excecute that time Admin User comes  on LastModifiedBy

Comment: @user4812 LastModifiedBy is used as example. you can change it to owner on any other field of your interest (which is referring to users table)

Comment: Updated my query with code that print Contact Name And Profile name